# Questioning who is the real Achashverosh

Tags: history, gentiles, names, purim

So I am doing very much research and I am trying to find out the REAL Achashverosh, so far, there are several possible rulers of Persia that could be the real Achashverosh

Can anyone of you guys suggest the most possible one/ones that rabbis most agree on? Thanks!

Comment: http://seforim.blogspot.com/2013/02/identifying-achashverosh-and-esther-in.html

Comment: Thanks, this really contributes a lot to my research to the real Achashverosh!

Comment: Suggestion .. Dress 3 Persian men to look like kings and put them on a game show that has 4 panelists and a host. You never know, but it may be worth $500 to the winner.

Comment: I'm not really sure that it's Xerxes I, because many Jewish sources say it's Artaxerxes I. But this is the best question yet that will help determine who is Achashverosh, what year was the Beit Hamikdash sheni complete? Thanks!

Comment: Please guys do you know what year the second temple was rebuilt please no jokes

Comment: @AvishaiEliYahu 3408 from Creation, or c. 350 BCE.